# Tagging Elastic Search Slow Query

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

My ElasticSearch cluster is in AWS cloud and is on version 7.8. I am trying to tag my elastic search queries so that I can identify who are the originators of the slow queries once I have them in the slow query log. I went through the elastic.co guide [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/app-search/7.8/analytics-tags-guide.html) which outlines the procedure to use analytics key to add tags to the query.

However, when I run my query with the analytics tag I get the error below. Also, PFA below a snapshot of the query and response.

Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong ?

Secondly, If analytics tag is something which is not available in AWS ElasticSearch then can someone suggest that what could be the alternatives to tag my queries ?

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [analytics].",
        "line" : 156,
        "col" : 16
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [analytics].",
    "line" : 156,
    "col" : 16
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

[image: Query and Kibana Response]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you're referring to is for [App Search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/app-search/7.8/index.html) which is another product of the Elastic Stack but not Elasticsearch itself.

What you need to do instead is to use [named queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.8/query-dsl-bool-query.html#named-queries) which allow you to do pretty much the same as you expect.

What you can do is simply tag the top-level `bool` query

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "_name": "your-client-tag",
    "must": [
      {
       "bool": {
```

Comment: Thanks. Isn't there a top level field where I can just add the user-id which takes care of tagging ? I mean adding the same user-id to all the sub-queries may not be the best way to go about ?

Comment: You don't need to add it to all sub-queries just one, since the whole query is going to get logged in the slow log, you just need a "signal"

Comment: Thanks. However, I see that my queries already have multiple *_name* embedded in them. You can look up the query here : https://pastebin.com/qfGC3tfP . Isn't there a top level attribute which lets me tag the query like it's happening using the analytics tag ?

Comment: See my updated answer. You just need to tag the top-level bool query and you're good to go

Comment: How do I tag suggest queries. _name will work for query but not for suggest.

Comment: suggest queries are named by definition, so in your response you get that name as well.

Comment: So, How will I add a tag here ?

POST _search
{
  "suggest": {
    "text" : "tring out Elasticsearch",
    "my-suggest-1" : {
      "term" : {
        "field" : "message"
      }
    }
  }
}

If I add something like tag then I need a field
"_name" : {
      "term" : {
        "field" : "What should It be which doesn't hit query performance ?"
      }
    }

Comment: Can you create a new question since this now concerns suggest queries while the initial question concerned search queries

Comment: Created a new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66641341/tagging-slow-elastic-search-suggest-query