# Tagging Slow Elastic Search Suggest Query

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

My ElasticSearch cluster is in AWS cloud and is on version 7.8. I want to tag my elasticSearch suggest queries so that I can identify who are the originators of the slow suggest queries once I have them in the slow suggest query log. I received a [response from @Val](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66595705/tagging-elastic-search-slow-query#comment117798386_66595901) for my [query question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66595705/tagging-elastic-search-slow-query) who suggested that suggest queries are named by default so we can use it but I am unable to understand how ? Can someone suggest what to do ? What should be the field so that it doesn't add to additional latency ? I tried with the query below.

```
POST kibana_sample_data_ecommerce/_search
{
  "suggest": {
    "_name" : {
      "text" : "ClientIdAndTraceId",
      "term" : {
        "field" : "What should be the field here ?"
      }
    },
    "my-suggest-1" : {
      "text" : "Oceanavigations",
      "term" : {
        "field" : "manufacturer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am unable to understand what should be the field so that it doesn't add to additional latency or query getting timed out ? If there is any other alternative then please let me know that too.

Answer (score 0):

For suggesters, it's not possible to add names like for queries.

What you could maybe try is to use the name of the suggest query (i.e. `my-suggest-1`) to tag the suggest query

```
POST kibana_sample_data_ecommerce/_search
{
  "suggest": {
    "use-this-name-to-tag-your-suggest-query" : {        <------- see this
      "text" : "Oceanavigations",
      "term" : {
        "field" : "manufacturer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
1. Isn't there a way to add metdata to queries which helps in tagging it ? This is more like a workaround.
2. Can I add another suggest parameter so that I don't have to modify the existing queries which doesn't add to latency ?

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't. Feel free to file a feature request if you think this can be beneficial

Comment: As per the communication from ElasticSearch team they suggested to use X-Opaque-Id https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/70417